# Subset dataframe into equal subgroup chunks

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have `df` dataframe that needs subsetting into chunks of 2 `names`. From example below, there are 4 unique names: `a,b,c,d`. I need to subset into 2 one column matrices `a,b` and `c,d`.

Output format:

```
name1
item_value
item_value
...
END
name2
item_value
item_value
...
END
```

Example:

```
#dummy data
df <- data.frame(name=sort(c(rep(letters[1:4],2),"a","a","c")),
                   item=round(runif(11,1,10)),
                   stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
#tried approach - split per name. I need to split per 2 names.
lapply(split(df,f=df$name),
       function(x) 
       {name <- unique(x$name)
        as.matrix(c(name,x[,2],"END"))
       })

#expected output
[,1] 
[1,] "a"  
[2,] "8"  
[3,] "9"  
[4,] "6"  
[5,] "4"  
[6,] "END"
[1,] "b"  
[2,] "2"  
[3,] "10" 
[4,] "END"

[,2] 
[1,] "c"  
[2,] "6"  
[3,] "6"  
[4,] "2"  
[5,] "END"
[1,] "d"  
[2,] "4"  
[3,] "1"  
[4,] "END"
```

**Note:** Actual `df` has ~300000 rows with ~35000 unique names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this.

```
# for each 'name', "pad" 'item' with 'name' and 'END'
l1 <- lapply(split(df, f = df$name), function(x){
  name <- unique(x$name)
  as.matrix(c(name, x$item, "END")) 
  })

# create a sequence of numbers, to select two by two elements from the list
steps <- seq(from = 0, to = length(unique(df$name))/2, by = 2)

# loop over 'steps' to bind together list elements, two by two. 
l2 <- lapply(steps, function(x){
  do.call(rbind, l1[1:2 + x])
})

l2
# [[1]]
#      [,1] 
# [1,] "a"  
# [2,] "6"  
# [3,] "4"  
# [4,] "10" 
# [5,] "3"  
# [6,] "END"
# [7,] "b"  
# [8,] "6"  
# [9,] "7"  
# [10,] "END"
# 
# [[2]]
#     [,1] 
# [1,] "c"  
# [2,] "2"  
# [3,] "6"  
# [4,] "10" 
# [5,] "END"
# [6,] "d"  
# [7,] "5"  
# [8,] "4"  
# [9,] "END"
```

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked the way you wanted! Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making the lists from individual names make it from the column of subsets of the data.frame

```
res <- list("a_b" = c(df[df$name == "a",2],"END",df[df$name == "b", 2],"END"),
        "c_d" = c(df[df$name == "c",2],"END", df[df$name == "d", 2],"END"))

res2 <- vector(mode="list",length=2)
res2 <- sapply(1:(length(unique(df$name))/2),function(x) {
  sapply(seq(1,length(unique(df$name))-1,by=2), function(y) {
    name <- unique(df$name)
    res2[x] <- as.matrix(c(name[y],df[df$name == name[y],2],"END",name[y+1],df[df$name == name[y+1],2],"END"))
  })
})
answer <- res2[,1]
```

This is giving me a matrix of lists since there are two sapplys happening, I think everything you want is in res2[,1]

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I need an automated approach. Real `df` has ~300000 rows with ~35000 unique names.

Comment: then you should have asked the question so that answering it would get you the result you want. what does the data actually look like and want do you really want? 2 lists of 17500?

Comment: The opposite, 17500 matrices each having 2 names.

Comment: your lapply function there makes lists

Comment: Sorry, maybe it is not clear. I need a list of 17500 one column matrices each having 2 names.